# Arrow button using layer-list

Tags: android

I spent hours trying to implement the follofing button using `layer-list` drawable but had no success:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: why do you want to use a layer-list specifically?

Comment: I would use a nine-patch

Comment: To tell the truth I use Xamarin and it would be great to use vector-based images not png as much as possible.

Comment: There's a start here (https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/) on the triangle part in XML as a LayerList, but the consensus in the comments is to go with a 9-patch